# Spring SOAP webservice - change response namespace prefix

Tags: spring, soap, spring-ws

I'm producing SOAP webservice with Spring like this tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/
Everything works fine, but it is a little problem: when I do request on my method, responsed XML s wrapped into "ns2" namespace prefix. I want to change "ns2" into my own custom prefix to meet business requirements. Any ideas ??

Comment: In its current version, the question is not meaningful. "ns2" is not a namespace, but a namespace prefix, and as such completely arbitrary. If the question is really about changing the namespace prefix, then you should explain why you want to do this and clarify the question.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538896/is-it-possible-to-rename-th-response-namespace-prefix-in-a-spring-ws-webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538896/is-it-possible-to-rename-th-response-namespace-prefix-in-a-spring-ws-webservice)
this answer helps me.