# Is it possible to rename th response namespace-prefix in a Spring WS webservice?

Tags: spring, web-services, jaxb, xml-namespaces, spring-ws

I've build a *Spring WS webservice* based on the example at http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/. The response contains my namespace with the prefix "ns2".

```
xmlns:ns2="http://www.mycompany.com/somewhere"
```

**Soap-Response**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:mitteilungResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.mycompany.com/somewhere">
         <ns2:responseContent>
            <ns2:message>Hello World!</ns2:message>
         </ns2:responseContent>
      </ns2:mitteilungResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is it possible to rename that prefix to "myprefix"? How? Anybody?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, i found the solution. It's pretty easy... Simply add it to the @XmlSchema-Annotation in the **package-info.java** as follows:

```
@XmlSchema(
    xmlns = { 
        @XmlNs(prefix = "myprefix", namespaceURI="http://www.mycompany.com/foobar")
    },
    namespace = "http://www.mycompany.com/somewhere",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package com.mycompany.project;
```