# Java and Soap Web Service | Why do namespaces prefix changes automatically from ns2 to ns4 on migration?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, namespaces

Soap Service Migration changes namespace prefix on web service response:

Earlier it was:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body>
<ns2:GetProjectsResponseType 
xmlns="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/common" 
xmlns:ns2="http://tsb.eto.com/terp/ws/schema" 
xmlns:ns3="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/project" 
xmlns:ns4="http://tsb.eto.com/tsb" 
xmlns:ns5="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/customer" 
xmlns:ns6="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/servicecontract" 
xmlns:ns7="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/task" 
xmlns:ns8="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/offering" 
xmlns:ns9="http://psi.eto.com/kil/system/message">
```

Now it changes to:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body>
<ns2:GetProjectsResponseType 
xmlns="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/common" 
xmlns:ns2="http://tsb.eto.com/terp/ws/schema" 
xmlns:ns3="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/servicecontract"  <------
xmlns:ns4="http://tsb.eto.com/tsb" 
xmlns:ns5="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/customer" 
xmlns:ns6="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/project" <-----
xmlns:ns7="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/task" 
xmlns:ns8="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/offering" 
xmlns:ns9="http://psi.eto.com/kil/system/message">
```

What could be reason of change in this namespace?

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tsb.eto.com/terp/ws/v2", name = "Terp-v2")
@XmlSeeAlso({com.eto.psi.tsb.schema.common.ObjectFactory.class, 
    com.eto.psi.tsb.schema.offering.ObjectFactory.class, 
    com.eto.psi.kil.system.message.ObjectFactory.class, 
    com.eto.tsb.terp.ws.schema.ObjectFactory.class, 
    com.eto.psi.tsb.schema.task.ObjectFactory.class, 
    com.eto.psi.tsb.schema.servicecontract.ObjectFactory.class, 
    com.eto.psi.tsb.schema.project.ObjectFactory.class, 
    com.eto.tsb.tsb.ObjectFactory.class, 
    com.eto.psi.tsb.schema.customer.ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface TerpV2 {

   @WebMethod(operationName = "GetServiceContracts")
   @WebResult(name = "GetServiceContractsResponseType", targetNamespace = "http://tsb.eto.com/terp/ws/schema", partName = "payload")
   public com.eto.tsb.terp.ws.schema.GetServiceContractsResponseType getServiceContracts(
       @WebParam(partName = "payload", name = "GetServiceContractsType", targetNamespace = "http://tsb.eto.com/terp/ws/schema")
       com.eto.tsb.terp.ws.schema.GetServiceContractsType payload
    ) throws TerpServiceFault;

    and so on all operations are defined (without above sequence)
```

Package Info has something like this for all ns's:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/servicecontract", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.eto.psi.tsb.schema.servicecontract;
```

There is no such listing of namespace and operation name mapping. tried removing Xmlnsfor qualified with no desirable results.

Reason: Customer had old code not ready to change and hardcoded namespaces.

Comment: You must understand that the meaning of a namespace is defined by its _namespace name_ (the `http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/servicecontract` part). The only thing that a _namespace prefix_ (the `ns2` part) provides is a convenient shortcut for a _namespace name_ and carries no implicit  meaning itself. It is therefore perfectly legal to change the _namespace prefix_ at will.

Comment: @ThomasKläger: Customer has not change the Client code. 
He want same namespaces as he is getting many issues due to same. I am not sure why he hardcoded it 10 years ago. But technical debt is there. Found this one: Trying it too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538896/is-it-possible-to-rename-th-response-namespace-prefix-in-a-spring-ws-webservice . any more help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use the Package Info to completely fix the namespace mapping:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/servicecontract",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns = {
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "ns2",
               namespaceURI="http://tsb.eto.com/terp/ws/schema"),

        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix="ns3",
               namespaceURI="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/project")
        // include the remaining namespace declarations
  )
)
package com.eto.psi.tsb.schema.servicecontract;
```

Source: [JavaDoc for `XmlSchema`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html), example 2.

Note that this works only if all messages have the exactly same namespace mapping.

---

IMHO this should only be a workaround. You should urge your customer to adapt proper namespace handling ASAP.

Comment: Thanks. I have given like above but there is one namespace. It shows like underscore at end. Any idea to fix this?

xmlns:ns9="http://psi.eto.com/kil/system/message" 
xmlns:ns9_="http://psi.eto.com/tsb/schema/common">